# How to change WordPress api v2

Tags: rest-api

I am working at mobile android app. I want use WordPress api so I need to add new tables to WordPress api layer like shop and hospitals

Comment: if the api do not fit your needs, you should write your own

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

You should write a plugin to create and mantain extra taxonomies (shop, hospitals, like you said) and manage the custom API endpoints.